# Fetch API inside a class function

Tags: javascript, class, fetch, destructuring

I'm having trouble with destructuring an object that is returned from the fetch api in my Aztro class.

I've tried various way to destructure it at random with no success....

If i return it instead of console logging, how do i access it? See the code and comments for further clarification of my questions.

The reason i want to do this is because the api will only return one zodiac sign at a time.

```
 class Aztro {
  constructor(sign){
    this.sign = sign
  }
  getData(){
    return fetch('https://example/?sign=' + this.sign + '&day=today', {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( data =>  {
      console.log(data) // how do I destructure this if it's returned and not just console.log()
    })
  }
}

let aries = new Aztro('aries')      // Can pass in zodiac signs to fetch data
let aquarius= new Aztro('aquarius')

aries.getData()     // this logs the json data in the console....

// EDIT this is how I tried to destructure it 

const {description} = aries
const {description} = aries.getData() // this returns Object promise when i tried to output it to the dom 
const {description} = Aztro
```

Comment: Please show the destructuring code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the fetched data in two manner:

1- using promise chain, like this:

```
aries.getData().then(data => console.log(data))
```

2- using `async/await` to fetch data.The important point in using `async/await` is that you have to call await keyword just inside an async function (the reason I defined `app` function in below code) like this:

```
class Aztro {
  constructor(sign){
    this.sign = sign
  }
  async getData(){
    const response = await fetch('https://example/?sign=' + this.sign + '&day=today', {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
}

async function app(){
  let aries = new Aztro('aries')      // Can pass in zodiac signs to fetch data
  let aquarius= new Aztro('aquarius')
  const data = await aries.getData();
  console.log(data);
}
app();
```